# When using jQuery mobile, refresh is needed for page to display as intended

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM's listview as a navigation for one mobile website I am creating. Nothing fancy, just a mobile version of a regulr website. However, there are some problems.

When the page is loaded, and when clicking on particular links, the site is not shown in a way it is supposed to. For example, page named "what we do" uses fontawesome icon set, only afetr reloading the page, the icons are shown. Also, on the "what've done" only afer reload the jQuery gallery plugin is working correctly.

Here is the website in question: http://www.m.gowb.net

Comment: It is working fine for me, I am using iPad right now. It could be a browser issue. Which browser are you using to test the page?

Comment: Windows phone 8, opera mobile emulator, and desktop Firefoy and Chrome.

Comment: Try upgrading Jquery mobile to 1.2.0 and JQuery to 1.8.3, it could solve the problem. Use CDN hosted if you want, http://jquerymobile.com/download/ what we do page is not working now, I can't see the icons.

Comment: I will try, but not sure. Icons are only displayed after resfreshing the page.

Comment: You have font-awesome css link duplicated inside <head> tag. Plus I can't see <HTML> tag.

Comment: You have a problem on "what we do" page, on portrait view only. Check this http://tinypic.com/r/juwvvm/6 the rest of the pages are okay on both landscape and portrait.

Comment: Yes I know, I changed something now, it is because of that.